# jquery load based on href

Tags: jquery, load

I am having a link

```
<a id="test" href="text.php">test</a>
```

I have the following jquery code

```
    $("#test").live("click", function(){                       
             $("#myDiv").load($("#text").attr("href"));         
        });
```

trying to load  the href of #test inside myDiv.

But of course when click, start .load the href AND the browser changes to text.php.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add `return false;` to your click handler:

```
$("#test").live("click", function(){                       
  $("#myDiv").load($("#text").attr("href"));         
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a jQuery-specific way of doing this but I forget what it is :-) but you can add `return false` to your anonymous function:

```
$("#test").live("click", function(){                       
  $("#myDiv").load($("#text").attr("href"));    
  return false;     
});
```

which should prevent the default action happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it

```
$("#test").live("click", function(e){    
      e.preventDefault();                   
      $("#myDiv").load($("#text").attr("href"));    

    });
```